# `react-truncate` Package does not work when built and used

Tags: reactjs, multiline, ellipsis

Getting error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in Truncate.js

`<Truncate lines={1} onTruncate={this.handleTruncate} > {value} </Truncate>`

Comment: Where "value" variable comes from ? Maybe it is undefined.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini `value` comes from `props`. It is not `undefined`, I have even added hard coded value for `value`.

Comment: I found your open issue on the repo, have you read this issue ? https://github.com/One-com/react-truncate/issues/25 ?

Comment: I have just checked the issue, seems like the fix should already be a part of `v2.4.0` which I am using.

Comment: Could you post a codepen reproducing the issue ? if you need a codepen react template I can provide one